# NPM npm_package_main variable is always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, npm, package.json

## Problem

NPM `$npm_package_main` variable is always empty.

1. When I set the package.json file with `"main": "index.js"`
2. Set the "start" property from scripts to `"start": "node $npm_package_main"`
3. Then run `npm start`

**Problem**: the CLI executes the Node REPL mode, ignoring the "main" variable from package.json.

**Expected behavior**: execute the command as `node index.js`.

### Environment

- Linux Ubuntu 20.04.1
- `npm -v` = 7.3.0
- `node -v` = v15.5.0
- `npm run env | grep npm_package_name` = `npm_package_name=app`
- `npm run env | grep npm_package_main` = EMPTY

### How to reproduce

- Create an "app" directory and enter the new directory
- Create an "index.js" file with the following content
  `console.log('HELLO');`
- Run `npm init` and hit ENTER for all questions
- Edit the `package.json` file and add the following line to the "scripts" property:
  `"start": "node $npm_package_main",`
- now your package.json must look like this

```
    {
      "name": "app",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "devDependencies": {},
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node $npm_package_main",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

- Run "npm start"
- File "index.js" is not executed and Node enters the REPL mode.

### Attempts

Set "start" and running "npm start" for:

- "echo $npm_package_main" prints nothing
- "echo $npm_package_name" prints "app"
- "echo $npm_package_version" prints "1.0.0"

### References

- NPM package.json variables: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts
- NPM Github issue: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2585

Comment: Yeah, you can just set "start": "node index.js" and it works, But the "$npm_package_main" is not working. That's the point.

Answer (score 7):

- The official answer from NPM: use "node .". There's no official reason for this behavior, until this post.
- According to the documentation, the "main" property contains the entrypoint for your app when is used as a module in other projects: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#main

## Solution

- Use the "config" property instead:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "config": {
    "main": "index.js"
  },    
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node $npm_package_config_main",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

- Run "npm start"
- It works

### References:

- https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2585
- https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/2446

Comment: [A comment from the linked github issue mentions that removing `npm_package_main` was intentional](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2585#issuecomment-770418809), while the current (`v9.x.x`) `npm` docs still suggests that _all_ `package.json` members should be accessible as `npm_package_`-prefixed environment variables. Running `npm run env | grep npm_package_`  proves that this is no longer true 
, but was it ever explained anywhere _why_ this changed?